# How to split select statement into mutiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, sql-server-2012

I am having select statement retrieving results as shown below

```
ID  Name    CASETYPE 
1   Anil    TR
2   Sam     CR
3   Samuel  TR
4   Satish  CR
5   Kumar   CI
```

My Query Is:

```
SELECT max(ID),max(Name),casetype FROM TABLE GROUP BY CASETYPE
```

Expected OutPut:

**table1**

```
ID  Name    CASETYPE 
1   Anil    TR
2   Samuel  TR
```

**table2**

```
ID  Name    CASETYPE    
1   Sam     CR  
2   Satish  CR
```

**table3**

```
ID  Name    CASETYPE    
1   Kumar   CI
```

Comment: Does SQL Server really accept "SELECT * FROM TABLE GROUP BY CASETYPE"?!?

Comment: So you want to return 3 result sets?

Comment: How does your table data look in this case?

Comment: yes i want to return 3 results seperatly. I have just written sample data. @FelixPamittan

Comment: You mean the first data is table data, and not returned from your select?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to do this. But here is one way using a `CURSOR` and dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @caseType VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT CaseType FROM tbl ORDER BY CaseType DESC

OPEN cur
FETCH FROM cur INTO @caseType

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'SELECT ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID), Name, CaseType FROM tbl WHERE CaseType = @caseType'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@caseType VARCHAR(2)', @caseType

    FETCH FROM cur INTO @caseType
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: This is dynamic and should work better as compared to the other answer. +1

Comment: @Vic, the OP wanted an individual result for each `CASETYPE`. If the `CASETYPE`s are known, then there is no need for a `CURSOR` and dynamic SQL. Three separate queries with `WHERE` clause for each `CASETYPE` will be enough. However, if there are unknown number of `CASETYPES`, the `CURSOR` and dynamic SQL will be better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how you expect your current query to return more than 1 row for each casetype, the aggrigates will only return 1 row per casetype.

It is not possible to split a select into different tables. Try this instead:

```
CREATE table table1(ID int identity(1,1), Name varchar(10), CASETYPE char(2))
CREATE table table2(ID int identity(1,1), Name varchar(10), CASETYPE char(2))
CREATE table table3(ID int identity(1,1), Name varchar(10), CASETYPE char(2))

INSERT table1(Name, CASTTYPE)
SELECT Name, CASETYPE 
FROM yourtable
WHERE CASETYPE = 'TR'


INSERT table2(Name, CASTTYPE)
SELECT Name, CASETYPE 
FROM yourtable
WHERE CASETYPE = 'CR'

INSERT table3(Name, CASTTYPE)
SELECT Name, CASETYPE 
FROM yourtable
WHERE CASETYPE = 'CI'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
Declare @temp1 Table
(
  caseType varchar(2)
)
Declare @ResultTable  Table
(
  id int,
  name varchar(50),
  casetype varchar(2)
)
Insert into @temp1 
select distinct casetype from Table_1
Declare @caseType varchar(2)
While((Select Count(*) From @temp1)>0)
Begin
   Set @caseType=(Select Top 1 casetype From @temp1)

   Insert Into @ResultTable 
   select * from Table_1 Where casetype=@caseType

   select * from @ResultTable

   delete from @ResultTable
   Delete @temp1 Where caseType=@caseType
End
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @CaseTypeCount TINYINT           --Variable to store the Distinct case type count 
DECLARE @IteratorForCaseType TINYINT = 1 --Iterator for looping

/* get the ditinct case type count */
SELECT @CaseTypeCount = COUNT(DISTINCT CASETYPE) FROM YourTable

/* Loop for all distinct case types */
WHILE (@IteratorForCaseType<= @CaseTypeCount)
BEGIN
/* Use a Common table expression to manipulate thetemperory results */
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASETYPE DESC) AS RowID,
CASETYPE
FROM
YourTable
GROUP BY
CASETYPE
)

SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ) AS ID  
,Name
,YourTable.CASETYPE 
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN 
YourTable
ON YourTable.CASETYPE = CTE.CASETYPE
WHERE RowID = @IteratorForCaseType

SET @IteratorForCaseType +=1

END
```